# ONNX ORT_INVALID_ARGUMENT(2) exception when creating tensor with Ort::Value::CreateTensor

Tags: c++, machine-learning, onnx, onnxruntime

I am trying to create a tensor for ONNX with `Ort::Value::CreateTensor` using the following snippet:

```
Ort::MemoryInfo MemoryInfo = Ort::MemoryInfo::CreateCpu(OrtAllocatorType::OrtDeviceAllocator, OrtMemType::OrtMemTypeCPU);


std::vector<Ort::Value> vInputTensors;
    
for (std::vector<float> vfInput : TestDataset.GetInputs()) {
    unsigned uSequenceLength = vfInput.size();

    // Shape: (batch_size=1, sequence_length, num_norm_attributes, num_channels=1)
    const std::vector<int64_t> vi64InputShape = {BATCH_SIZE, uSequenceLength, 2 * NUM_ATTRIBUTES, NUM_CHANNELS};

    Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(MemoryInfo, vfInput.data(), uSequenceLength, vi64InputShape.data(), vi64InputShape.size());
    //vInputTensors.push_back(Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(MemoryInfo, vfInput.data(), uSequenceLength, vi64InputShape.data(), vi64InputShape.size()));
}
```

I have printed the elements in `vfInput.data()` and `vi64InputShape.data()` and printed the values of `uSequenceLength` and `vi64InputShape.size()`. And everything is a expected.

However, the program throws an exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC7ABDCF19 in TestApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Ort::Exception at memory location 0x00000036901AF6B0.
```

When I change `BATCH_SIZE, uSequenceLength, 2 * NUM_ATTRIBUTES, NUM_CHANNELS}` to `{BATCH_SIZE, 100, 2 * NUM_ATTRIBUTES, NUM_CHANNELS}`, it doesn't complain but of course that's not correct.

Please may you assist me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you compare `vi64InputShape.size()` to uSequenceLength, exactly? Because the former is always 4. uSequenceLength should be equal to the **product** of the elements in vi64InputShape...

Comment: Thanks so much @Botje. This fixed my problem. Been stuck on it for quite a while. Also forgot that I flattened my array so the correct sequence length is actually `vfInput.size()/(2 * NUM_ATTRIBUTES * NUM_CHANNELS)`. Thanks again.